# YAML file requires different amounts of indentation for different nodes

Tags: yaml, artillery

I'm attempting to write a YAML config script for a load testing utility called Artillery.

The YAML syntax is not making any sense to me though. Artillery appears to deserialize the YAML to a Javascript object syntax so it expects nodes in the YAML file to have a certain structure.

```
config:
  target: https://mhhs-prod-webapp.azurewebsites.net/
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 50
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - get:
      url: '/'
```

Given the above file though it fails complaining that `'get' must be of type object`. In the file above the `get` node has a child node `url` of key value type, so I'm expecting it to be of type `object`.

After much trial and error I've managed to get it to work using the following layout.

```
config:
  target: https://mhhs-prod-webapp.azurewebsites.net/
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 50
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - get:
        url: '/'
```

But the bizarre thing is that this file is identical to the previous one apart from the fact that the `url` node is indented 4 spaces instead of the 2 spaces of indentation used throughout the rest of the file.

Is this correct? I'm having trouble finding an explanation of YAML that is understandable but so far I haven't come across anything that suggests that different amounts of indentation do completely different things.

Comment: I'll just summarize my answer o'er here. It's like Python indentation, you mistakingly indent it and you make a lot of unintended consequences.

Comment: I added a second comment to my last comment. I might've forgot to mention you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hohoho, I understand how you feel about [YAML indentations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_indentation_and_separation.htm).

It's like Python-based indentation but with a mix of JSON.

In your code:

```yaml
  config:
    ...
  scenarios:
    - flow:
      - get:
        url: '/'
```

"url" looks like a child of "flow" since it has an indent like so.

It can go in a couple of routes.

Route #1: (Where "url" is under "flow:")

```yaml
  ...
  scenarios:
    - flow:
      - get:
      - url: '/'
```

Route #2: (Where "url" is under "get:")

```yaml
  ...
  scenarios:
    - flow:
      - get:
        - url: '/'
```

Route #3: (Where "url" is under~ uhm...)

```yaml
  config:
    ...
  scenarios:
    ...
  url: '/'
```

Comment: Surely in your duplication of my example `url` is a child of `get` not a child of `flow`. It's indented under `get`.

Comment: @Neutrino If you take a look at it, it goes with the same indentation as "get", and "get" is under "flow", that means that "url" is also a child of "flow". A parent can have as many child(s) (or children) as necessary.

Comment: `- get` is indented 4 spaces, `url` is indented 6 spaces. Are you suggesting that whether a value is considered indented or not is dependent on whether or not its parent starts with a `- ` and if so the `- ` is ignored and the parent and child items are pretended to be at the same indentation level?

Comment: @Neutrino I am sorry but you are very wrong (but you corrected yourself at the very end though), "- get" is indented 6 spaces, the " - " is for readability hence it is ignored and considered as "whitespace".

Comment: I noticed the silence, yes the " - " is for readability AND for declaring a list item. All I said there was that "- get" and "url" technically have the same indent value once evaluated.

Comment: So whether it's considered indented or not isn't based purely on whether it's actually indented, but on whether it's indented and whether it has a `- ` in front of it, so it can actually be indented but considered not indented. Thanks I understand enough now to get this to work. I must say though that has to be the singular most stupid parsing rule I've ever come across in 25 years of programming.

Comment: @Neutrino As a self-taught youngin', I agree with you, basing indentation on the words themselves and not the symbols before them looks stupid and confusing enough that it did took me 5-10 mins to realize that it was like that when I first tried YAML.